# how to integrate the crosswalk WebView Annex phoneGap?

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build, crosswalk-runtime

I work in windows 8. To compile just create a file and load it into Adobe PhoneGap Build. How to make an application to compile to a plugin Crosswalk?

The link https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/3347
they say that you just need to add a line in the config:

```
<gap:plugin name="org.crosswalk.engine" version="1.3.0" />
```

But it does not give any result. The application is compiled as before, without Crosswalk. On the tab, with the list of plug-ins, is still empty [enter link view screenshot](http://easycaptures.com/fs/uploaded/873/6318093306.jpg)

I would be very grateful for any help

Comment: Did you tried to add the plugin via CLI `cordova plugin add http://github.com/phonegap-build/cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview.git` ?

Answer (score 0):

For Phonegap Build, try these two lines in your config.xml

```
<preference name='phonegap-version' value='cli-5.1.1' />
<gap:plugin name='org.crosswalk.engine' version='1.3.0' source='pgb' />
```

Source:
http://phonegap.com/blog/2015/06/16/phonegap-updated-on-build/

Answer (score 0):

You can use this plugin

```
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview-pgb-adapt" source="npm" version="1.4.0-dev-5"/>
```

instead of

```
<gap:plugin name="org.crosswalk.engine" version="1.3.0" />
```